# Method for string input to binary string?

Tags: java, methods

Need to make a method for taking an input, num= stdIn.nextLine(); and converting it into a binary string. "public static String toBinary(String num)". In Java. Any ideas? Can only find for int to binary. Needs to be string so user can enter "q" to exit program.

Comment: What do you mean by converting a string to a binary?  That's not a natural conversion, which is why there isn't a pre-existing function to do it.  What binary would "blat" convert to?  Or, which strings to you want to convert to "true" and which to "false"?

Comment: user will only be entering numbers, need to be printed as binary. Have to make a method that takes the number, divides by 2 and uses the remainder to make binary. Then divides by 2 and continues. How do i make a method for that?

Comment: Oh, I was totally misreading what you need to do (conflating binary with boolean). If you already have a method to convert from an int to a binary, you can just parse the string as an integer.  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static String toBinary(String num) {
    int convertedNum = Integer.parseInt(num);
    return Integer.toBinaryString(convertedNum);
}
```

Note that you should catch possible runtime exceptions because of the integer conversion of the String value.

I hope I helped you!

Comment: where is the binary code stored? What would I add to print?

Comment: The binary code string is returned by the method. You would have something like this: System.out.print(toBinary(num));

Answer (score 0):

```
public String toBinary(String num){
    return Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(num));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String toBinary (String num) throws NumberFormatException {
  int n = Integer.parseInt(num);
  return Integer.toBinaryString(n);
}
```

This assumes you checked for "q" before calling the method (or you can catch it when the exception is thrown if you prefer, but that's not as clean IMO)

Comment: would you write the throws part, or just from int n= down?

Comment: Yes, I would write the throws part.  Since it's a runtime error, you don't have to declare it, but parseInt will throw it if you pass it a string that isn't an integer, and you should catch it on the call and print out a complaint if the user entered bad input.